# JSON object description in IE11 is it possible

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

Here is the situation,

I have the following sample input:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1836",
        "lead_id": "2967",
        "form_id": "10",
        "field_number": "1",
        "value": "Davis May 08",
        "is_synced": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "1837",
        "lead_id": "2967",
        "form_id": "10",
        "field_number": "3",
        "value": "Kevin",
        "is_synced": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "1838",
        "lead_id": "2967",
        "form_id": "10",
        "field_number": "4",
        "value": "Test",
        "is_synced": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "1839",
        "lead_id": "2967",
        "form_id": "10",
        "field_number": "5",
        "value": "2018-05-08",
        "is_synced": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "1840",
        "lead_id": "2967",
        "form_id": "10",
        "field_number": "6.1",
        "value": "725 Fieldcrest Dr Unit A",
        "is_synced": "1"
    }
]
```

However, when code goes through the following output:

```
for(i in responseArray) {

        var item = responseArray[i].evalJSON();

        // Format Dob
        if (item.field_number == '5') {
            item.value = intlToUsDate(item.value);
            console.log(item.value);
        }

        var inputSelector = '[name="input_' + item.field_number + '"]';
        var dom_elms = document.querySelectorAll(inputSelector);

        for (var e in dom_elms) {
            var dom_elm = dom_elms[e];
            if (dom_elm.type == 'radio' || dom_elm.type == 'checkbox') {
                if (dom_elm.value == item.value && !dom_elm.checked) {
                    dom_elm.click();
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                dom_elm.value = item.value;
            }

        }
    }
```

and it produces the following output:

"

i
d
"
:

"
1
8
3
6
"
,

"
l
e
a
d
_
i
d
"
:

"
2
9
6
7
"
,

"
f
o
r
m
_
i
d
"
:

"
1
0
"
,

"
f
i
e
l
d
_
n
u
m
b
e
r
"
:

"
1
"
,

"
v
a
l
u
e
"
:

"
D
a
v
i
s

Note this only happens in IE11.  I saw somewhere that development for IE11 stopped and that is why I can't handle the json.object .

Correct?

Comment: Format your JSON in your post, bud!

Comment: Produces the output where? Of course IE 11 can parse JSON. Include a  [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It supposed to produce an output to an form,but it is not.